# ODE help with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Initial conditions are $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0$

Applying the Laplace Transform to both sides and simplifying I reach the form

$$ L(y) = \frac{s^3 + 5s}{s^2 + 4}, $$

which I then further simplify in the following steps

$$ L(y) = \frac{s(s^2 + 5)}{(s^2 + 4)(s^2 + 9)} $$

$$ L(y) = \frac{s(s^2 + 4 + 1)}{(s^2 + 4)(s^2 + 9)}$$

$$ L(y) = \frac{s}{s^2 + 9} + \frac{s}{(s^2 + 4)(s^2 + 9)}. $$

I know the first term to be the Laplace of $\cos(3x)$ , but when I solve for the other term I reach a result of

$$ L^{-1}\biggl[\frac{s}{(s^2 + 4)(s^2 + 9)}\biggr] = \frac{4}{5}\cos(3x) + \frac{1}{5}\cos(2x) $$

Giving a final result of

$ y = \cos(3x) + \frac{4}{5}\cos(3x) + \frac{1}{5}\cos(2x) $

Which I know to be incorrect after approaching the problem with the method of undetermined coefficients. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to solve a differential equation by Laplace transform, the initial conditions are necessary. Where are they?

Comment: The solution you have is almost correct. The first term, however, should be nonexistent. Edit: There is something very wrong here. Why on earth did you add that term in the beginning for no good reason?! Your inverse laplace step was the correct answer!

Comment: No the $\cos(3x)$ term. Okay I see the problem, hmm, there must be an algebra mistake somewhere in the set up. The answer should just be what you have on the right because that matches both the initial conditions and the inhomogeneous term.

Comment: I included more of my work if you are willing to further help. I have spent the past couple of hours on this problem and feel like I am hitting my head against a wall because I cannot find where I have went wrong haha. Thank you.

Comment: My thought process is that there is no sin term in the solution so I must've made a mistake. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'' + 9y = \cos(2x)$$
$$\implies r=\pm3i$$
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos 3x + c_2 \sin 3x$$
Then for the particular solution
$$y_p=A\cos (2x) \implies A=\frac 15$$
The solution is therefore:
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos (3x) + c_2 \sin (3x) +\dfrac 15 \cos (2x)$$
Apply initial conditions:
$$c_2=0 \text { and } c_1=\frac 45$$
So that:
$$y(x)=\frac 45 \cos (3x)+\dfrac 15 \cos (2x)$$
Note that you have a little mistake in the fraction decomposition
$$ g(s)=\frac{s}{(s^2 + 4)(s^2 + 9)}=\frac s 5 \left(\frac{1}{(s^2 + 4)}-\frac{1}{(s^2 + 9)} \right)$$
$$\implies g(x)=\frac 1 5 (\cos (2x)-\cos(3x))$$
And you get the same answer:
$$y(x)=\frac 45 \cos (3x)+\dfrac 15 \cos (2x)$$

Comment: You have a litele mistake in the fraction decomposition

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The homogeneous equation is a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficient. These equations are very well known. Now, a particular solution will be of the form $$\alpha \cos(2x)+\beta \sin(2x).$$

Combine both yields the right solution.